# Construct a branch of $\sqrt{\log z}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Construct a branch of $\sqrt{\log z}$ on the upper half-plane $\left\{z \in \mathbb{C}: \operatorname{Im} z>0\right\}$. Justify your answer.

Not sure if my constructed branch is correct.
considering each part separately,

I know
$$\sqrt{w}=\sqrt{r}e^{\frac{i\arg z+2\pi{k}}{2}}: k=0,1$$

and $\log{z}=\log|z|+i\,\arg{z}$
are multi-valued,
so If we fix say $k=1$, and take $\arg\,z$ to be the principle argument $-\pi<\mathrm{\arg}\,z\leq\pi$ is this an acceptable branch?

Comment: What is $n$? Maybe it would help to use a different letter than $z$ in discussing the square root function and be explicit there about the branch cut possibilities.

Comment: apologies I will change "K = 0,1"  and I will change z to w, I suppose the branch cut possibilities would be the roots of $\sqrt{w}$ which are found by substituting the possibilities of K namely 0,1 for $w^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Comment: Why do you remove a whole ray to define a branch of log, but not for the square root?

Comment: I am not quite familiar with what you mean by a ray? I am trying to learn an introductory class in complex analysis sorry.

Comment: In your definition of arg(z), you let its values be between $-\pi$ and $\pi$, but in fact since your $\log(z)$ is only on the upper half plane, only values between $0$ and $\pi$ show up. this should help you construct a branch of the square-root.

Comment: @KentaS I had completely forgotten that requirement, so instead if the argument was as you said, $0\leq{argz}\geq\pi$ and we fix k=0, then we would have the k=0 branch of $\sqrt{\log{z}}$? forgive me if there is something that conflicts that I am completely missing

Comment: @JamieWard to be precise, since the upper half plane does not include the real line, you have $0<arg z<\pi$. So now you only need to define the square root on the upper half plane, which is do-able by the same method.

Comment: does this restriction of $argz$ not already restrict the square root to the upper plane?

Comment: A ray is a half-line. This is a term from high school (typically). Not fancy advanced math. Think about the domain of log; what did you remove?

Comment: @TedShifrin my bad, I understand what you mean now. we removed [0,1]?

Comment: For the principal branch of log, you remove the negative real axis (and the origin); as you wrote it — not actually removing it — you end up with discontinuities along that negative real axis.